# Spring JPA how to create tables so I can share common ID?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to create messages system in Spring. I will have 3 models and 2 forms. What I want to do is:
1)Create a table "conversations" = done
2)Create new entry in table "conversations" with converstion id and conversation subject = done.
4)create new table "conversations_members"
5)Create two new entrys in table "conversations_members" , one with `conversation_id`, `sender_id`, `lastviewed date`, `isdeleted = 0 (false)` and `conversation_id`, `receiver_id`, `lastviewed_date`, `isdeleted=0(false)`
6)I next form, with reply i would like to generate entry in "conversations_messages" with message_id (autogenerated, Long id), conversation_id, message_date and messate_text.

I dont know how to connect all `conversation_id` in 3 tables. I think that would be "one to many" option, but how to use it? 
Best regards, Jędrzej.

**Conversation model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conversation")
public class Conversation {

@Id
@Column(name = "conversation_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "conversation_subject")
private String subject;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Conversation(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Conversation() {

}

}
```

**ConversationMembers model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="conversation_members")
public class ConversationMembers {

@Column(name="conversation_id")
private Conversation conversation;


@Column(name="user_id")
private SiteUser user;

@Column(name="conversation_deleted",  columnDefinition="Integer(0,1) default '0'")
private int conversationDeleted;


@Column(name="column_last_viewed")
private Date date;


public Conversation getConversation() {
    return conversation;
}


public void setConversation(Conversation conversation) {
    this.conversation = conversation;
}


public SiteUser getUser() {
    return user;
}


public void setUser(SiteUser user) {
    this.user = user;
}


public int getConversationDeleted() {
    return conversationDeleted;
}


public void setConversationDeleted(int conversationDeleted) {
    this.conversationDeleted = conversationDeleted;
}


public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}


public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public ConversationMembers(Conversation conversation, SiteUser user, int    conversationDeleted, Date date) {
    this.conversation = conversation;
    this.user = user;
    this.conversationDeleted = conversationDeleted;
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

**ConversationMessage model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="conversations_messages")
public class ConversationMessages {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="message_id")
private Long messsageId;

@Column(name="conversation_id")
private Conversation conversation;

@Column(name="message_date")
private Date message_date;

@Column(name="message_text")
private String text;

public Long getMesssageId() {
    return messsageId;
}

public void setMesssageId(Long messsageId) {
    this.messsageId = messsageId;
}

public Conversation getConversation() {
    return conversation;
}

public void setConversation(Conversation conversation) {
    this.conversation = conversation;
}

public Date getMessage_date() {
    return message_date;
}

public void setMessage_date(Date message_date) {
    this.message_date = message_date;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public ConversationMessages(Long messsageId, Conversation conversation, Date   message_date, String text) {
    this.messsageId = messsageId;
    this.conversation = conversation;
    this.message_date = message_date;
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

**NewConversation.jsp**

```
<form:form commandName="conversation">
<br>

<form:form commandName="conversationmembers">
To:
<form:input path="userid" type="text" name="userid" />
SUBJECT
<form:input path="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    <button type="submit" value="start conversation" />

</form:form>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use relations. Just use annotations to do so. Refer http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-and-jpa-integration

Answer (score 0):

According your question i understand you want to make relation.so you can use something like that

**Conversation**

```
@Entity @Table(name = "conversation") public class Conversation {

@Id
@Column(name = "conversation_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "conversation_subject")
private String subject;

@OnetoMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<ConverstaionMessage> message;

@OnetoMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<ConverstaionModel> message;
```

// getter setter so on

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Conversation(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Conversation() {

}

}
```

and also you can use 
@ManyToOne in ConversationMessage and ConversationModel

Comment: well I want to have in "conversation" just two fields = conversation_id, conversation_subject.

Comment: Ok so remove list above and add manytoone and joincolumn in others